# Deploying keycloak docker image to heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, jboss, keycloak

I am trying to deploy my custom keycloak docker image which is extended from jboss/keycloak to heroku container stack.

Its deployed successfully but it errors out saying permission denied on start itself.

I am new to heroku container. Can some one help me please?

Here is my heroku.yml file

```
    addons:
        - plan: heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
          as: DATABASE
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
```

here is my docker file

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
ENV DB_PORT 5432
ENV DB_DATABASE mydatabase
ENV DB_USER myuser
ENV DB_PASSWORD mypassword
ENV DB_VENDOR postgres
ENV DB_ADDR postgres
ENV KEYCLOAK_USER mykeycloak
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD mykeycloakpassword
ENV PORT 8080
COPY standalone.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/standalone.xml
COPY standalone.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
COPY meraklis /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/mytheme
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss/tools
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and here are the errors in heroku logs

```
2020-03-18T05:07:02.975073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `-b 0.0.0.0`
2020-03-18T05:07:05.796708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-18T05:07:05.773550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2020-03-18T05:07:05.733774+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that it actually is not heroku issue but docker one. Heroku does not allow to run any script or command as root while running the container. It adds a dummy non-root user to container and the container run under that user context under workdir you specified in dockerfile. You need to give execute permission to the shell script in order to make it run properly. That was the issue in my case

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I have a docker image that runs fine locally, but I"m seeing that the permissions are all janky when run in heroku.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Yes it is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) You should test your docker image locally with non root user.

Answer (score 1):

Need some tweaks to work with heroku. I tried this https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/keycloak-heroku and succeeded, live demo: https://unisso.herokuapp.com/.

Deploy with one click:

[image: Deploy to Heroku]

Source code: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/keycloak-heroku

### Caveats:

The free dyna can't be used since the keycloak requires more resources. So you need to pay $7 per month for the minimal viable dyno:

[image]

Comment: Yes I too got it working. My problem was in how I was building my docker image. Actually I needed to customize the original jboss/keycloak image for my reqruiements.

Comment: With this solution, Aren't you paying $250/month for the performance-m dyno?

Comment: @Jeff I am also interested in this? are you banking 250 for a single KeyCloak instace?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i fixed it, you just need to give permission to the docker-entrypoint.sh from git like this  `git add --chmod=+x -- docker-entrypoint.sh`